# Toggle image in UICollectionViewCell when cell selected

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView of items, and I would like an image in a cell to be toggled when the user selects the cell.

I have a custom UICollectionViewCell:

```
class RDCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var textLabel: UILabel!
var imageView: UIImageView!
var isSelected: Bool!

...(do init and all that good stuff)

}
```

And selctected item in collection view :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    let celld = (collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? RDCell)!

    let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()

    let newCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! RDCell
    if(celld.selected){

        var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "notSelected")!
        newCell.imageView.image = image

        newCell.selected = false
    }else{
        var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "selected")!
        newCell.imageView.image = image

        newCell.selected = true
    }

return true
}
```

My attempt partially works, after selecting and unselecting one item I am not able to select it again after, I need to select a different cell before returning to select the first, and this same bug happens on all selected cells.

Any suggestions or another way to implement the functionality I seek would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This probably has to do with the fact that your are checking if celld is selected, but then change the newCell. Does it work if you don't use the newCell and execute all the code on celld?

Comment: Why code is not placed insde `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: @Eric, I tried not using the newCell and I could not get the image to change at all on the original cell.

Comment: @Pyro, probs because I was following an answer that used that on my last attempt and this is the closet I have to working, I'll switch it to didSelectItemAtIndexPath and give that a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *never* call cellForItemAtIndexPath directly. You have no guarantee of what cell you're getting and the changes you make may have no effect.

The proper way to do this is to track your state within the class and change the state of the cell in cellForItemAtIndexPath. Then you simply call `collectionView?.reloadData()` when you need to update the views.

Simple example for reference:

```
var selectionTracking: [[Bool]] = []


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    if let selected = selectionTracking[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] {
        return selected
    }
    else{
        selectionTracking[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] = false
    }
    return true
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let selected = selectionTracking[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] {
        selectionTracking[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] = !selectionTracking[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    }
    else{
        selectionTracking[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] = true
    }

    collectionView?.reloadData()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Swift 4

I just use the property "highlightedImage" in the "cellForItemAt indexPath" method of the collectionView and set another image on it.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    imageView.image = imagesArray1[indexPath.row]
    imageView.highlightedImage = imagesArray2[indexPath.row]
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return cell
}
```

In my case, i assigned a tag in the imageView and call it through it.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

My approach will be different for this, i would have used the didDeselectItemAt method of the collectionView...

**Swift 3:**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let newCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    newCell.imageView.image = imageAfterSelection[indexPath.row]
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let newCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) 

    newCell.imageView.image = imagesAfterDeselection[indexPath.row]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4/5:**

Inside your **collectionViewCell class** define a variable called **imageName**
then *override* **isSelected** property to set the image name based on selected state and in **collectionView cellForItemAt** method set the value for imageName variable for each cell.

**CollectionViewCell Class:**

```
class YourCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
{

    @IBOutlet var cellIcon: UIImageView!

    var imageName = ""

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if self.isSelected {
                self.cellIcon.image = UIImage(named: "\(self.imageName) Highlighted")
            } else {
                self.cellIcon.image = UIImage(named: "\(self.imageName) Unhighlighted")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**CollectionView DataSource:**

```
class YourCollectionVewController: UICollectionViewDataSource 
{

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // this line is an extension don't copy paste
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(with: YourCollectionViewCell.self, for: indexPath) 

        let imageName = "yourImageName Unhighlighted"
        cell.cellIcon.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        cell.imageName = imageName

        return cell
    }
}
```